# onOptionsItemSelected not registering for items In Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a fragment with a `NavigationView` which is using a menu with three items. However, whenever I click the menu items, the `onOptionsItemSelected()` function is not called.

This `NavigationView` is being used in a drawer and the `onOptionsItemSelected()` function works when opening and closing the drawer, just not when clicking the menu items.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Fragment Class:**

```
public class Navigation extends Fragment {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    return view;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //Opens and closes drawer
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.new_flight: Log.d("SELECTED", "new_flight");
            break;
        case R.id.saved_flight: Log.d("SELECTED", "saved_flight");
            break;
        case R.id.settings: Log.d("SELECTED", "settings");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Fragment XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.craig.flightfinder.Navigation"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/mainNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `OnCreateOptionsMenu` inside your fragment. From your code for fragment, it looks like you are not inflating the menu resource inside your fragment.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
}
```

where my_menu resource file has your items with the desired ids

Answer (score 0):

**1.add `your_menu.xml` at `res/menu` folder.**

**2.Add `onCreateOptionsMenu`**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override onNavigationItemSelected instead of onOptionsItemSelected and always return true.

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     ...
     return true;
}

Answer (score 0):

You are delegating `onOptionsItemSelected()` from the activity/fragment to the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` then consume the event by this:

```
if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
{
     return true; //consume the event that handled by drawer toggle.
}
```

So you should implement how your drawer toggle react to the `optionsItemSelected` event by overriding it's own `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)`. See the code below:

```
mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch(item.getItemId())
      {
           case R.id.new_flight: Log.d("SELECTED", "new_flight");
                break;
           case R.id.saved_flight: Log.d("SELECTED", "saved_flight");
                break;
           case R.id.settings: Log.d("SELECTED", "settings");
                break;
           default:
                break;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What exactly is mToolbar supposed to be? Do I need to create one?

Comment: @Craig how is it? Do you need any help?

Comment: Thanks for the edit,  I still can't seem to get it to work. I have put the code in the onCreateView function. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. What did you get till now? Does the `onOptionsItemSelected` inside `new ActionBarDrawerToggle() { }` get called?

Comment: Yes, the function only seems to register when the draw is opened and closed, not when the items are selected.